# I am trying to create two return statements in react native, getting an error Unreachable code detected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is a snippet of my Code

```
class FoodOne extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'FoodOne'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
            
                <Text>FoodOne Component</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                navigate('Food')
                }}> 
                
                </TouchableOpacity>
               <Image
                 // HOW DO I// SIDE BY SIDE IMAGES 
                style={styles.image} source={require('./images/husker.jpg')}
                />
                <Image
              style={styles.image} source={require('./images/giants_helmet.jpeg')}/>
            </View>
        )
```

I am trying to add this return statement

```
return(
  <View>
    <Image
      style={styles.image} 
      source={require('./images/giants_helmet.jpeg')}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: what is two return statements supposed to do?

Comment: Kindly specify clearly how you want the UI to work then can help you with.

Comment: I am trying to post another picture in the second return section but getting an error "Unreachable code detected"

Comment: could you pls update your answer with the layout u r expecting

Comment: Thanks for all the responses,,  Under my second return statement

Comment: under my second return statement return(
  <View>
    <Image
      style={styles.image} 
      source={require('./images/giants_helmet.jpeg')}
    />
  </View>
);

Comment: it is dim in my code with an error as I hover over it that "Unreachable code detected"  I am trying to post pictures in the app but the last picture is not loading, only the first two pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing two returns just add the code to the bottom of first return. Functions die after running one return, so they cant run two returns.

```
class FoodOne extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'FoodOne'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
            
                <Text>FoodOne Component</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                navigate('Food')
                }}> 
                
                </TouchableOpacity>
               <Image
                 // HOW DO I// SIDE BY SIDE IMAGES 
                    style={styles.image} 
                    source={require('./images/husker.jpg')}
                />
                <Image
                    style={styles.image} 
                    source={require('./images/giants_helmet.jpeg')}/>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image} 
                    source={require('./images/giants_helmet.jpeg')}
                />
            </View>
        )
```

And if you want these images to be side by side then you should styles. Flexbox specifically. so code to make these 2 images side by side is:

```
class FoodOne extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'FoodOne'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
            
                <Text>FoodOne Component</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                navigate('Food')
                }}> 
                
                </TouchableOpacity>
               <View 
                   style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}
               >
                   <Image
                     // HOW DO I// SIDE BY SIDE IMAGES 
                        style={styles.image} 
                        source={require('./images/husker.jpg')}
                    />
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image} 
                        source={require('./images/giants_helmet.jpeg')}/>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image} 
                        source={require('./images/giants_helmet.jpeg')}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
```

The last two images are the same but that is so in your code and i dont know if that is intended so i left it that way. I hope i understood right, have a good day.

Comment: Thanks mobileHelper, what I would like to do is place the first two images side by side and then place the third image below on the first two that is centered.. any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.  I will continue to do research on Flexbox to figure this out!  Thanks!

Comment: Hello mobileHelper,  thanks again for your help, I think I figured out that I can have nested VIEW, here is a small segment of my code .

Comment: <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Image       style={styles.image} source={require('./images/49ers.png')}/>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                navigate('Dolphins')
                }}> 
                <Text> QuarterBacks </Text>                         
                <Image 
                style={styles.image} source={require('./images/dolphins.png')}
                /> </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>   <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }

Comment: I could not show you all my code but, I did nested views and it seems to work!!  THANKS for your help!!  Have a great day!!

Comment: Sorry I was busy yesterday, happy if I helped.

Comment: Btw just a reminder: For React Native functional components are rather more popular now. You might wanna look into them and how to use react hooks to manage them.